# Как в Yii2 записывать данные сразу в 2 таблицы?

Tags: mysql, yii2

Есть две связанные таблицы: в первой хранятся посты блога, во второй - картинки к посту.
Картинок может быть неограниченное количество.
Нужно при создании поста записывать сам пост в одну таблицу, а картинки к нему - в другую. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Только двумя запросами. Проблема в том, что значение ссылающегося поля для таблицы картинок будет получено только после фиксации вставки в таблицу постов. Т.е. второй INSERT только после завершения первого INSERT.

Comment: Вот в коде который gii генератор делает вообще нет insert, там через $model->save() всё отрабатывается как я понимаю

Comment: Кажется понял, можете тогда еще подсказать как записывать массив данных? У меня получается пути картинок придут массивом.

Comment: _там через $model->save() всё отрабатывается_ Но до MySQL-сервера всё равно доберутся SQL-запросы. И их должно быть два на добавление, да плюс ещё один. Может ли _$model->save()_ обеспечить выполнение первого запроса на добавление (первый запрос к серверу), получение сгенерированного автоинкрементом значения ключа (второй запрос!) и выполнение второго запроса на добавление (третий запрос!) с подставленным туда значением полученного значения автоинкремента - понятия не имею... Конечно, избавиться от промежуточного запроса формально можно, но только формально.

Comment: Либо на каждую картинку своя запись, что удобно и логично, либо serialize($arr_images) перед записью, а при выборке unserialize($row['images'])